# Grails spring-security-facebook plugin's accessToken

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, grails, spring-security

I'm using the spring-security-facebook plugin for authentication. It works well, now I'm trying to use some functions of spring-social-facebook that needs authorization. From my controller, where can I get a valid accessToken (in order to create a FacebookTemplate object) ?

This is how I'm using the plugin:

1) I added a domain class, OAuthUser (not in the plugin but in my project)
2) I have generated a FacebookAuthDaoImpl
3) I edited the methods generated, for example in create(), I create 
    + an instance of a user (main domain class SecUser) and set the profile infos 
    + a new OAuthUser (where I set the uid, the accessToken, and relate it to the main user created.

**UPDATE 1:**
I added those 3 methods in my FacebookAuthDaoImpl class:

```
Boolean hasValidToken(OAuthUser user){
    def now= new Date()

    if(now.after(user.accessTokenExpires)){
        return false
    } else {
       return true  
    }
}

void updateToken(OAuthUser user, FacebookAuthToken token){

    user.accessToken = token.accessToken
    user.save()
}

String getAccessToken(OAuthUser user){
    return user.accessToken
}
```

But I still have the expired AccessToken.

Comment: but where you're updating `user.accessTokenExpires`? what `hasValidToken` returns if it's null?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I don't, I'm trying to figure out from where can I get the expiration date. Do you have a sample or something ? (btw I figured out how to get the accessToken from authentication `FacebookAuthToken token = SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication
     token.accessToken = facebookAuthUtils.getAccessToken(token.code)` )

Comment: void updateToken(OAuthUser user, FacebookAuthToken token) {
    user.accessToken = token.acceessToken.accessToken
    user.accessTokenExpiration = = token.acceessToken.expireAt
}

Comment: @IgorArtamonov are hasValidToken() and updateToken() called by the plugin ? or do I need to add the call myself in FacebookAuthDaoImpl ? in this case where ? because the only place where I have the token is when create() is called (and this call is made juste first time user login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **default DAO**:

It's stored at field `accessToken` of your domain object for Facebok User.

If you don't have field named `accessToken`, you should add it (`String accessToken`). Ideally with an additional field: `Date accessTokenExpires`. And both fields will be automatically filled by the plugin.

If you've created your **own DAO** implementation, then:

- `create(FacebookAuthToken token)` pass access token as `token.accessToken.accessToken`. You can store it anywhere you wish
- `Boolean hasValidToken(F user)`, `void updateToken(F user, FacebookAuthToken token)` and `getAccessToken(F user)` - first should check token expiration, second update with new value (called when token is expired) and last should retourn current value.

As you said, you have you own DAO implentation. How you're implemented last 3 methods?

Comment: Igor, I already have an accessToken field in my OAuthUser domain class (without the accessTokenExpires date). When using it, I get an expired access token exception

Comment: I belive for Facebook User you're using different domain, right? I mean it's seems to be domain for another plugin, possible oauth auth

Comment: Yes @Igor, I have created an OAuthUser domain linked to my main user. There's no other plugin involved

Comment: ok, so, this domain is configured for 'grails.plugins.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname', right? At this case, try to add `accessTokenExpires` field. W/o such field plugin doesn't know that token is expired